# Zig import and use of C libraries: too many (conflicting?) ways

Tags: zig

I'm wrapping a low level C library (networking) in zig.

Building it requires a number of compiler flags, defines, etc.. For this I specify all that in my build.zip adding defines, paths, flags, source code files. This works 100%.

Now, to actually use the code, I have to import it. Again, no brainer:

```
// main.zip
const net = @cImport({@cInclude("net_device.c");});                                                                      
net.find_device(...);
```

When building this leads to a dup-symbol linker error presumably because zig has two copies one from build.zip and one from cImport:

```
error: ld.lld: duplicate symbol: find_device
```

My dilemma:

- I can't just cImport the code (and omit buid.zig work) b/c it'll build wrong
- I can't just do the build.zig work (and omit cImport) b/c I can't call it

How to resolve? Is there something I can do in build.zip to make it come in conceptually equivalent to addPackagePath for regular zig code?

Answer (score 2):

Well, duh: The correct way to fix this problem is:

```
// WRONG! main.zip
const net = @cImport({@cInclude("net_device.c");});                                                                      
net.find_device(...);
```

and correct to cImport net_device.h:

```
// RIGHT! main.zip
const net = @cImport({@cInclude("net_device.h");});                                                                      
net.find_device(...);
```

The upshot is ... if you need fancy build options, do those in build.zig, but when you import code only import function decls.